# button with copytoclipboard functionality on odoo 16

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, odoo

I'm looking for a way to get the functionality of `copytoclipboard` on a button on wizard in Odoo 16. This button should be copying the text from a 'TEXT' field on the same wizard, share your valuable feedback.

I already tried to bring in the Odoo widget for copying text to the field from which I need to copy text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.